# Command of files and size

Tags: file-type

is there a command to list what type of files are in a directory and the size?

for example, .jpg 1GB, .png 2GB, .avi 3GB etc. , thanks

Answer (score 7):

You could use `file` to determine the actual file type (MIME type) based on its content instead of the file extension, and you can use pure Bash to aggregate the size sum per type.

Have a look at this example:

```bsh
$ find Pictures/ -printf '%s\t' -exec file --brief --mime-type {} \;|{ declare -A A;while IFS=$'\t' read -r B T;do A["$T"]=$((A["$T"]+B));done;for T in "${!A[@]}";do printf '%12d\t%s\n' "${A["$T"]}" "$T";done;}|sort -bnr
    72046936    image/jpeg
    57324445    image/png
    23712181    application/x-7z-compressed
    17144737    image/gif
     6563757    image/x-xcf
      697098    image/svg+xml
       53248    inode/directory
```

And to verify the results, the sum of all values above is exactly equal to what `du` reports:

```bsh
$ du -sb Pictures/
177542402   Pictures/
```

Here's the used command-line from above commented and formatted in a more readable way as a script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# Recursively find all files (and directories) in `Pictures/`,
# then output their size on disk in bytes, followed by a tab and the output of `file`,
# showing only the short MIME type without path and extra info (e.g. "image/png"):
find Pictures/ -printf '%s\t' -exec file --brief --mime-type {} \; | {

    # declare the `ARR` variable to be an associative array (mapping type strings to total size)
    declare -A ARR

    # parse the above output line by line, reading the tab-separated columns into 
    # the variables `BYTES` and `TYPE` respectively
    while IFS=$'\t' read -r BYTES TYPE ; do
        # add the current `BYTES` number to the corresponding entry in our `ARR` array
        ARR["$TYPE"]=$(( ARR["$TYPE"] + BYTES ))
    done

    # loop over all keys (MIME types) in our `ARR` array
    for TYPE in "${!ARR[@]}" ; do
        # output the total bytes (right-aligned up to 12 digits) followed by a tab and the type
        printf '%12d\t%s\n' "${ARR["$TYPE"]}" "$TYPE"
    done

# sort the resulting output table numerically, in descending order and ignoring leading space
} | sort -bnr
```

Comment: You could greatly simplify this by using `awk` instead of the shell after the pipe: `find ... | awk '{a[$2]+=$1} END{for(i in a){print a[i],i}}'`.

Answer (score 5):

A method would be:

```
find . -name '?*.*' -type f -printf '%b.%f\0' |
  awk -F . -v RS='\0' '
    {s[$NF] += $1; n[$NF]++}
    END {for (e in s) printf "%15d %4d %s\n", s[e]*512, n[e], e}' |
  sort -n
```

Result from my Desktop:

```
  873172992    1 mkv
```

Comment: Thank you very much, i will try